# Pull Facebook graph into Google gadget as RSS

Tags: google-classic-sites, facebook-integration

How might I grab a public feed from graph.facebook.com and put it into a Google gadget as an RSS feed?

Example source: http://graph.facebook.com/prettyklicks/feed

Possible gadget to "eat" it with: http://www.google.com/ig/directory?url=www.google.com/ig/modules/feeds_tabs.xml

Answer (score 1):

The "feed" you specified is not an RSS or Atom feed, but a JSON one.
You need to consume and parse it programmatically, or use an online mashup tool like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to turn it into something a Google Gadget (or any other) can consume.

Comment: I know it's not rss. I'm asking how it could be turned into rss.

Comment: MAtt, there are several pipes on Yahoo pipes (like this: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=Qvdm_tq_3RGbo7Wt1JzWFw) and several other libraries that will turn JSON to RSS - all depends on your needs and medium.

Comment: Thanks for the direct link. I get empty results with that pipe, and several other similar ones, when directed at a facebook feed. Still testing others...

Comment: It is quite simple to develop. If you really need it, we can talk offline. Good luck.